# react filter first three of every type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-filter

I am making a react project and at one point, I have an API which returns the following:

```
APIresult = [
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "honey"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "milk"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "biscuit"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "tea"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "coffee"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "pillow"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "bedsheet"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "tv"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "fridge"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "airconditioner"
    },

]
```

I want to filter this array so that I get the first three of every category. 
ie, the result that I am expecting is

```
APIresult = [
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "honey"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "milk"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "biscuit"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "pillow"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "bedsheet"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "tv"
    }

]
```

I know I have to do APIresults.filter over it but how do I limit the result to just the first 3 of every type?

Comment: Please read the MDN documentation on Array.protorype.reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Will do, @BenBieler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce` to filter and froup your array so that the first three elements of each category are available and then join the results within an array again

```js
const APIresult = [
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "honey"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "milk"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "biscuit"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "tea"
    },
    {
        category: "first",
        value: "coffee"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "pillow"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "bedsheet"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "tv"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "fridge"
    },
    {
        category: "second",
        value: "airconditioner"
    },

]

const res = [].concat(...Object.values(APIresult.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(acc[item.category] && acc[item.category].length < 3) {
      acc[item.category].push(item);
   } else if(!acc[item.category]) {
       acc[item.category] = [item];
   }
   return acc;
}, {})))
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hey @Shubham, I'll be honest, I don't understand entirely how this works, so I'll put in more time to understand the logic, but I got the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: To give a  brief, we use reduce to generate and O/P like `{ first: [{}, {}, {}], second: [{}, {}]}}` . Once we have that we just get the values against object keys as arrays with Object.values. O/P will be `[[{}, {}, {}], [{}, {}]]`. Then we use spread syntax with array.concat to flatten this array

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem here is another solution, pack them into 2 arrays and then just filter those arrays to the the first 3 records

```js
arr = [{
    category: "first",
    value: "honey"
  },
  {
    category: "first",
    value: "milk"
  },
  {
    category: "first",
    value: "biscuit"
  },
  {
    category: "first",
    value: "tea"
  },
  {
    category: "first",
    value: "coffee"
  },
  {
    category: "second",
    value: "pillow"
  },
  {
    category: "second",
    value: "bedsheet"
  },
  {
    category: "second",
    value: "tv"
  },
  {
    category: "second",
    value: "fridge"
  },
  {
    category: "second",
    value: "airconditioner"
  },

]

const res = arr.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => y.length && y[y.length - 1].category === x.category);
  if (index < 0) {
    acc = [...acc, [x]];
  } else {
    acc[index].push(x)
  }
  return acc
}, []).flatMap(x => x.filter((y, i) => i < 3));

console.log(res)
```